# How can I replace a 'recvmmsg' call with multiple 'read' calls on a unix domain socket?

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, unix, python-3.6

I am converting a C++ unit test to a python functional test, and its proving to be difficult.

The test is reading from a unix domain socket. It first writes a simple message (string) then reads from the socket.

The unit test / compiled C++ program calls 'recvmmsg' to read from the socket. It uses the 'c message' paradigm. My functional test attempts to do the same thing, but from a strace I realize my functional test / python is ultimately simply calling 'read'.

I think part of the difficulty is that the unit test / unix domain socket is using this c message paradigm.

Here is my strace for the unit test / recvmmsg:

```
recvmmsg(3, {{
{msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\360", 1}], msg_controllen=20, [{cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, [5]}], msg_flags=0}, 1}, {
{msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\252", 1}], msg_controllen=20, [{cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, [6]}], msg_flags=0}, 1}, {
{msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\255", 1}], msg_controllen=20, [{cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, [7]}], msg_flags=0}, 1}, {
{msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\210", 1}], msg_controllen=20, [{cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, [8]}], msg_flags=0}, 1}, {
{msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\377", 1}], msg_controllen=20, [{cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, [9]}], msg_flags=0}, 1}, {
{msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\177", 1}], msg_controllen=20, [{cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, [10]}], msg_flags=0}, 1}, {
{msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\0", 1}], msg_controllen=20, [{cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, [11]}], msg_flags=0}, 1}, {
{msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\0", 1}], msg_controllen=20, [{cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, [12]}], msg_flags=0}, 1}}, 8, 0, NULL) = 8 (left NULL)
```

The actual data being read out is some file descriptors / integers. Inspecting the single line below, the [5] is the file descriptor, the rest is meta data.

```
{msg_name(0)=NULL, msg_iov(1)=[{"\360", 1}], msg_controllen=20, [{cmsg_len=20, cmsg_level=SOL_SOCKET, cmsg_type=SCM_RIGHTS, [5]}], msg_flags=0}, 1}
```

Stracing my python program however, it seems that only the msg_iov is being read, not sure why:

```
read(5, "\360", 8192)                   = 1
read(5, "\252", 8192)                   = 1
read(5, "\255", 8192)                   = 1
read(5, "\210", 8192)                   = 1
read(5, "\377", 8192)                   = 1
read(5, "\177", 8192)                   = 1
read(5, "\0", 8192)                     = 1
read(5, "\0", 8192)                     = 1
```

There is a lot more going on, such as using socat to translate the unix domain socket to a TCP socket. I have neglected to include code samples because they dont offer much more than the strace output.

Wondering on a very simple level if it is possible to replace a recvmmsg call with several 'read's. Logically, I would assume that if I did not read enough, my next read would pick up where the last left off. It seems it does not though, and just reads the msg_iov each time. Adjusting the buffer size in the python does not seem to change anything.

Am I attempting the impossible?

Comment: If you want the ancillary data in your python program, you need `recvmsg()`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvmsg

Comment: No, you cannot replace `recvmmsg` with multiple `read`s. You can with multiple `recvmsg`s (single m).

Comment: @e wagness - To reduce confusion, you shouldn't write _'c message'_ when you actually mean _ancillary
              message_.

Comment: Ah thank you all! both the C / Python code reference "C MSG:" so wasnt sure what to call it. Ok, so I am using recvmsg, but this gets translated to read() syscalls eventually (likely due to the odd socat thing i'm doing). @n.m. so its definitely impossible?

Comment: Yes definitely. recvmsg reads the ancillary message. read doesn't. You need it. The case is pretty clear.

Comment: @n.m. thank you! very helpful